# SQL How to get a business day of the month (excluding all holidays)

Tags: sql, date

I am trying to pull in my sql procedure sales report the current working day of a month and the time gone.

as for today:  `February Day: 9 Time gone: 45.0%`

as: `time gone = workingday_of_the_month / workingdays_of_(particular)month.`

Does anyone has an idea, how to pull the workingday and days excluding holidays?

Comment: Excluding holidays? Do you mean weekends or National holidays? Which country?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

This function allows you to enter the start and end date and it will return the elapsed number of working days.  The way I have used this is to add a table with UK public holidays. You can then use the function as part of your SQL query to calculate the 'time gone'.

```
--Create table with each public holiday, including Y/N for Weekday.
CREATE TABLE [holidays](
    [DayName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Weekday] [varchar](1) NOT NULL
    );

--2018 Bank Holidays
INSERT [holidays] ([DayName], [Date], [Weekday]) VALUES
    (N'New Years Day','2018-Jan-01','Y'),
    (N'Good Friday','2018-Mar-30','Y'),
    (N'Easter Monday','2018-APr-02','Y'),
    (N'Early May BH','2018-May-07','Y'),
    (N'Spring BH','2018-May-28','Y'),
    (N'Summer BH','2018-Aug-27','Y'),
    (N'Christmas Day','2018-Dec-25','Y'),
    (N'Boxing Day','2018-Dec-26','Y');

CREATE FUNCTION [WorkDayCount](
    @Startdate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    @Holidays int,
    @WorkDays int

SELECT @Holidays = COUNT(distinct Date) FROM HOLIDAYS 
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND [Weekday]='Y'

SELECT @WorkDays = ((
    -- Days between start and end dates
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate))
    -- Minus the number of weekend days between start and end dates
    -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
    -- Minus an extra day if starting on a Sunday
    -(CASE datepart(dw, @StartDate)+@@datefirst WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    -- Minus an extra day if ending on a saturday
    -(CASE datepart(dw, @EndDate)+@@datefirst WHEN 7 THEN 1 WHEN 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
    -- Minus Holiday Days
    - @Holidays)
RETURN @WorkDays
END
```